# play game service not authenticated if game upload to play store

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

some one help me please.
If the game has not been uploaded to play store the game can be authenticated.
but if the game has been uploaded to play store it can't be authenticated.
I use the latest Play Game Service SDK, I have added sha1 from the upload certificate or upload keystore to the game linked to the google play console play service

Answer (score 0):

This is an already [known problem](https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-services-not-working.485322/) with solution. Even though there's one answer lots of people are using from HanSoloYolo that says

> OK. So, This is how you fix it. When you uploaded your APK you used
> your SHA1 for the Uploaded Version. Google gives you a different SHA1
> AFTER YOU UPLOAD YOUR APK.
>
> You need to input this NEW SHA1 into your Credentials.
> ...

if you want it to work in production build, you'd need to would go with a mixture between what ferranases writes

> In linked aplications (Link Apps in Game Services), put you application twice

with what JACLEMGO writes

> one for the App Signing Certificate SHA1 and another using the Upload
> Certificate SHA1

Comment: As you suggested, I succes to added sha1 from upload certificate. But if i want to add sha1 from the app signing certificate it is failed. i can't add SHA1 from app signing certificate. it says SHA1 already exists. Strangely, I can't find sha1 from app signing certificate on my console.

Comment: @Iswahyudi in your Google Developer Console, in your app,  go to Release Management > App Signing. Then, notice there is an "Upload Certificate" and an "App Signing Certificate".

Comment: yes i can find that. i mean i can't crate an app that linked with sha1 from App Signing Certificate. said SHA1 already exists.

Comment: i have create 2 app that are linked at play service console. sha1 from Debug and sha1 from Upload Certificate

Comment: What do you mean two apps?

Comment: may be you can tell me how to add app linked with sha1 from App Signing Certificate. because i always fail to create it

Comment: my mean at "Google Play Console -> Play Service -> linked aplication. still one project game i added 2 app with different sha1.

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned by HanSoloYolo? If not, try it.

Comment: my game still not authenticated if i upload to play store

Comment: Please update your question with exactly what you've done.